# Equality of structure objects

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a tree structure in matlab like this:

```
node = 
  sub: [1x4 struct]
```

where each sub is also a node.

```
node.sub(1) = 
   sub: [1x4 struct]
```

etc. with leaf nodes having empty sub. Suppose I have a node and I am traversing down the tree. Is there any way to check if the node 'object' is the same as any in the tree? I am not talking about the value being the same. I want the 'object' to be the same.

For eg.:

```
mynode = tree.sub(1).sub(1);
isobjectequal(mynode, tree.sub(1).sub(1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `struct` in MATLAB is not technically an "object" in the sense that you're talking about it. If I create a struct and then assign it as a field within another struct, the two are now uncoupled. Any changes made to the first struct will not be reflected in the copy we just made.

```
a = struct('a', 2);
b = struct('b', a);

a.a = 3

% b.b.a == 2
```

You can really only reliably check that the *values* of two `struct`s are equal.

If you actually want to verify that the two `struct`s that you're comparing were created in the same way, you *could* go through the `struct` recursively and determine whether the [memory location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37157350/670206) of each element is the same in both structs. This would imply that the struct is both equal *and* they were created with the same underlying data.

For a very simple non-deeply nested struct this could look something like this.

```
function bool = isSameStruct(A, B)

    fmt = get(0, 'Format');

    format debug;
    memoryLocation = @(x)regexp(evalc('disp(x)'), '(?<=pr\s*=\s*)[a-z0-9]*', 'match');

    if isequaln(A, B)
        bool = true;
    elseif ~isequal(sort(fieldnames(A)), sort(fieldnames(B)))
        bool = false;
    else
        fields = fieldnames(A);

        bool = true;

        for k = 1:numel(fields)
            if ~isequal(memoryLocation(A.(fields{k})), memoryLocation(B.(fields{k})))
                bool = false;
                break;
            end
        end
    end

    format(fmt);
end
```

**Update**

An alternative is to use actual `handle` objects for your nodes. A basic class would look like this.

```
classdef Node < handle
    properties
        Value
        Children
    end

    methods
        function self = Node(value)
            self.Value = value;
        end

        function addChild(self, node)
            self.Children = cat(2, self.Children, node)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I missed this. That is why my tree modification code is not working. Do you know how to do something like traversing a tree and modifying it? The closest I found is this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793453/matlab-link-to-variable-not-variable-value

Comment: @TyanTowers Why not make your nodes actual `handle` objects?

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for "reference-equality" I guess you should use [handle](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html) objects:

> Use isequal when you want to determine if different handle objects
>   have the same data in all object properties. Use == when you want to
>   determine if handle variables refer to the same object.

*treeTest.m*

```
function treeTest()

root = TreeItem('Root');
child = TreeItem('Child');
grandChild = TreeItem('GrandChild');
grandGrandChild = TreeItem('GrandGrandChild');
grandGrandChild2 = TreeItem('GrandGrandChild');
root.Children{end+1} = child;
child.Children{end+1} = grandChild;
grandChild.Children{end+1} = grandGrandChild;
grandChild.Children{end+1} = grandGrandChild2;

findItem(root, grandGrandChild2)

    function findItem(tree, childToFind)
        if ~numel(tree.Children)
            return;
        end
        disp(['Traversing in ', tree.Name]);
        for i=1:numel(tree.Children)
            disp(['Iteration step: ', num2str(i)])
            if tree.Children{i} == childToFind
                disp(['Found! Name is ', tree.Children{i}.Name]);
                return;
            end
            findItem(tree.Children{i}, childToFind);

        end
    end
end
```

*TreeItem.m*

```
classdef TreeItem < handle
    properties
        Name;
        Children;
    end

    methods
        function obj = TreeItem(name)
            obj.Name = name;
            obj.Children = {};
        end 
    end
end
```

*The output is*

```
Traversing in Root
Iteration step: 1
Traversing in Child
Iteration step: 1
Traversing in GrandChild
Iteration step: 1
Iteration step: 2
Found! Name is GrandGrandChild
```

As you can see the two grand-grand-child object are equal in terms of properties, but the `Iteration step: 2` entry on the output proves, that the first grand-grand-child was skipped, because the function is searching for the second one.

The difference between `isequal` and `==`:

```
>> grandGrandChild = TreeItem('GrandGrandChild');
grandGrandChild2 = TreeItem('GrandGrandChild');
>> isequal(grandGrandChild, grandGrandChild2)

ans =    1

>> grandGrandChild == grandGrandChild2

ans =   0
```