# Will returned array be copied by value or returned as reference in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, reference, return

I wanted to ask how values in MATLAB are returned? Are they copied or passed by reference?

take a look at this example with matrix `A`:

```
function main
    A = foo(10);

    return;
end

function [resultMatrix] = foo(count)
    resultMatrix = zeros(count, count);
    return;
end
```

Does the copy operation take place when function returns matrix and assigns it to variable `A` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB uses a system known as [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) in which a copy of the data is only made when it is necessary (i.e. when the data is modified). When returning a variable from a function, it is not modified between when it was created inside of the function and when it was stored in a different variable by the calling function. So in your case, you can think of the variable as being passed by reference. Once the data is modified, however, a copy will be made

You can check this behavior using `format debug` which will actually tell us the memory location of the data (detailed more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157125/memory-allocation-for-function-calls-of-form-x-fx-in-matlab/37157350#37157350))

So if we modify your code slightly so that we print the memory location of each variable we can track when a copy is made

```
function main()
    A = foo(10);

    % Print the address of the variable A
    fprintf('Address of A in calling function: %s\n', address(A));

    % Modify A
    B = A + 1;

    % Print the address of the variable B
    fprintf('Address of B in calling function: %s\n', address(B));
end

function result = foo(count)
    result = zeros(count);

    % Print the address of the variable inside of the function
    fprintf('Address of result in foo: %s\n', address(result));

end

function loc = address(x)
    % Store the current display format
    fmt = get(0, 'format');

    % Turn on debugging display and parse it
    format debug
    loc = regexp(evalc('disp(x)'), '(?<=pr\s*=\s*)[a-z0-9]*', 'match', 'once');

    % Revert the display format to what it was
    format(fmt);
end
```

And this yields the following (or similar) output

```
Address of result in foo: 7f96d9d591c0
Address of A in calling function: 7f96d9d591c0
Address of B in calling function: 7f96d9c74400
```

As a side-note, you don't need to explicitly use `return` in your case since the function will naturally return when it encounters the `end`. `return` is only necessary when you need to use it to alter the flow of your program and exit a function pre-maturely.

Comment: I'm most grateful.